# Searching NSMenuItem inside NSMenu recursively

Tags: cocoa, recursion, nsmenu, nsmenuitem

The method `itemWithTitle` locates a menu item within a `NSMenu`. However it looks only inside the first level. I cannot find a ready-to-use method that will do the same job *recursively* by searching inside all the nested submenus. Or, somehow equivalently, a function that swipes `NSmenu`'s recursively.

It looks quite incredible to me that such a thing would not exist. Maybe there is some function not directly related to `NSMenu` that can come in handy?

Comment: It's not hard to code this yourself. But more to the point: why do you want this? I suspect that what you're trying to accomplish can be better accomplished some other way, such as via menu validation. (Which, by the way, is **why** what you find incredible might not be. There's really very little need for this functionality.)

Comment: @KenThomases I know it's not hard to do it myself, but before I reinvent the wheel I want to be 100% sure it's not already out there. Programmers should be lazy...

Comment: If you read the rest of my comment, you'll see I wasn't actually recommending that you code it yourself. I was saying that the desire to have this functionality indicates you're doing things (or trying to do things) the wrong way. You're fighting the frameworks.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm asking after all. Is there a proper way to do this, or would it be a clumsy workaround? I take it that it is the second case.

Comment: You haven't said what you're **really** trying to do. **Why** do you want to search for menu items by title throughout a menu hierarchy? What will you do with the menu item once you find it? Do a web search for "XY Problem" and read some of the top hits.

Comment: To make a long story short: I'm porting on mac a win app based on FLTK, which does clumsy things in clumsy ways. I am patiently and hopefully waiting for the day we'll do things properly, but until then my hand is forced to some workarounds. In this case I am trying to get a finer control over the menu bar (including images for example) and fix some aesthetic obscenities. I want to do this without hacking into third party libraries, so I was opting for writing a function that scrolls through the menu bar created by FLTK and does some cosmetics a posteriori. Now you know the ugly truth...

Comment: So the win app is written such that it expects to find a menu item by title? Or you're writing code to search for a menu item by title in order to implement your replacement for FLTK? Searching by title is bad because of localization or even just eventual UI rewording. It's safer to identify menu items by action or tag. The usual way to tweak items is for the class which implements the action method to also implement `-validateMenuItem:`. Or you can assign a menu delegate and implement some of the methods from `NSMenuDelegate`. Basically, have the menu items find you, don't look for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since I really need to do this clumsy workaround for a number of specific reasons (beyond the scope of this post, and quite uninteresting anyway) I ended up coding it myself.

Here is the snippet:

```
NSMenuItem * mitem;

while (mitem) { // loop over all menu items contained in any submenu, subsubmenu, etc.

     // do something with mitem ....

     mitem = next_menu_item(mitem);
}
```

which is powered by the functions:

```
NSMenuItem * goto_submenu(NSMenuItem * mitem){

    NSMenu * submen = [mitem submenu];
    if (submen && [[submen title] isNotEqualTo:@""] && [submen numberOfItems])
        return goto_submenu([submen itemAtIndex:0]);

    return mitem;
};

NSMenuItem * next_menu_item(NSMenuItem * mitem){

    NSMenu * menu = [mitem menu];

    if ([menu indexOfItem:mitem]==([menu numberOfItems]-1)) //if is last item in submenu go to parent item
        return [mitem parentItem];

    return goto_submenu([menu itemAtIndex:([menu indexOfItem:mitem]+1)]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation NSMenu (UT)

- (NSMenuItem *)itemWithTitle:(NSString *)title recursive:(BOOL)recursive {
    if (recursive) {
        for (NSMenuItem *item in self.itemArray) {
            if ([item.title isEqualToString:title]) {
                return item;
            } else if (item.submenu) {
                NSMenuItem *result = [item.submenu itemWithTitle:title recursive:recursive];
                if (result) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return nil;
    } else {
        return [self itemWithTitle:title];
    }
}

- (NSMenuItem *)itemWithTag:(NSInteger)tag recursive:(BOOL)recursive {
    if (recursive) {
        for (NSMenuItem *item in self.itemArray) {
            if (item.tag == tag) {
                return item;
            } else if (item.submenu) {
                NSMenuItem *result = [item.submenu itemWithTag:tag recursive:recursive];
                if (result) {
                    return result;
                }
            }
        }
        return nil;
    } else {
        return [self itemWithTag:tag];
    }
}
@end
```